# Android Marketplace not detecting minVersion setting in PhoneGap app’s config.xml

Tags: android, build, cordova

I have the following platforms block in my config.xml, but when uploaded to the Android Marketplace, it has an API Level of 2-12+ (which is a minimum android version of 1.1). I need to limit the app to 7-12+ (min version of 2.1), but for some reason the setting is not applied. Has this been implemented yet in PhoneGap Build, or am I missing something?

```
<gap:platforms>
    <gap:platform name="android" minVersion="2.1" />
    <gap:platform name="ios" />
</gap:platforms>
```

Just so we're clear, this is **PhoneGap *Build*** we're talking about.

Comment: is this an update or the first version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so everyone else knows, it would appear that your question has been addressed on [PhoneGap's GetSatisfaction page](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/android_marketplace_not_detecting_minversion_setting_in_config_xml_phonegap_build):

> **Hardeep Shoker (Official Rep)**
>
> Sorry for the confusion though the ability to specify it is present it needs to be integrated into build. We will look into it and post a notification once it has been completed.